# Change a single word background in a paragraph with CSS only (without changing HTML)

Tags: html, css

As a part of my study project, I need to change the background of a single word ("**adventure**") inside a paragraph. I'm not allowed to change HTML code, can use CSS only.

```
<p class="section_text">
  Welcome to adventure!
</p>
```

The only idea I have is to set a background to a pseudo-element `::after` and play with position relative/absolute, but it doesn't feel right.

```
.section_text {
  position: relative; }

.section_text::after {
  content: "adventure";
  background-color: #04128f;
  color: #0f0;
  width: 65px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 90px; }
```

Are there any smart ways to do that (it should work in the last version of Chrome)?
P.S. Can not use JS or jQuery neither. Exclamation sign background shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Please provide us with code that you tried. We shouldn't do your homework for you, but help you to achieve that goal based on what you tried.

Comment: No, changing the HTML according to the requirement would be the only smart thing to do here. If you are not allowed to do that, then you will have to find a way to fake it, by positioning something in the right position somehow.

Comment: You could probably position the pseudo element from the right edge of the paragraph, and have its content be `adventure!`, to automatically have it become the correct size. If the `!` needs to be excluded, things get a bit trickier - but the correct value for `right` in a font-size related unit like `em` would probably still be rather easy to figure out then.

Comment: you can change the html using jquery

Comment: a background maybe: https://jsfiddle.net/mLq8crfp/1/

Comment: there's no direct way to do this with css for the moment, you could use ::after or ::before and create an overlay below the word, but that won't work well if the text breaks, if size changes, if the position of the letter change. background position will suffer from the same issue unless you re-calculate it's position everytime a change happens (window resize, text breaking, etc...) your best bet would be something like this maybe, or even simpler, just use a span tag to modify the word you want

https://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set an intrinsic font-size to the `:root` selector. ex. `:root {font-size: 5vw}`. This makes the font responsive to viewport width.
2. Make the background of `<p>` the highlight color (ex red) and set its `width: max-content`.
3. Next `<p>` needs `position: relative` and then `z-index: -1`
4. Add two pseudo elements to `<p>`

   ```
   p::before {content: 'Welcome to';...}
   /*and*/ 
   p::after {content: '!';...}
   ```

   Assign `position: absolute`, `z-index: 1`, and `background: white`
5. Finally set `right: 0`to `p::after` so the exclamation mark is always at the very end

**Note:** the property/value `content: 'Welcome to\a0';` on  `p::before` selector has `\a0` at the end. This is the CSS entity code for a non-breaking space (HTML entity: `&nbsp;`)

```css
:root {
  font: 400 5vw/1 Consolas
}

p {
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
  z-index: -1;
  background: red;
}

p::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Welcome to\a0';
  background: white;
  z-index: 1
}

p::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '!';
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0
}
```

```html
<p>Welcome to adventure!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: to change background-color for an arbitrary position word, see [zer00ne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59302786/9787887) above. I didn't read the question thoroughly, so I wasn't aware that the OP wants the word `adventure` not `adventure!`

The smartest way to change any arbitrary word is to wrap it inside a `span` tag. Here's the workaround for changing the background of the last word: From your delivered code, `display: inline-block` for `p` tag, and don't set `width` for `::after` element.

```css
.section_text {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #3333;
  position: relative;
}

.section_text::after {
  content: 'adventure!';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="section_text">
  Welcome to adventure!
</p>
```